# CSS Debuggin for IE

Tags: css, debugging, internet-explorer

I'm seeing some really strange css float behavior in IE and I'm trying to diagnose the issue.  Is there an equivelent to Firebug or Chrome's "Inspect Element" in IE?

How do you typically debug CSS positioning issues in IE?

Comment: IE8 has a decent developer tool built-in. Press `F12`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options available, IE8 has a decent developer toolbar built in, you can access it by pressing F12 or if not going into the options menu and using developer tools, it doesn't work as well as firebug, but once you are able to select an element, you can easily change the styles. Firebug lite is another option though I havent used it in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)?

Answer (score 0):

IE9 has got great debugger, check it out. You can also set compatibility mode to IE8 or IE7 if you want.